# Compile fails for chained overloaded subscript operator[]

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, type-inference

I am trying to create a thin wrapper around some parsing libraries (JSON, YAML, etc.) which will allow me to use a unified syntax regardless of the file-type/parser I am using. I want the wrapper to leverage templating so I don't have to do any dynamic checks at runtime to check which library I am using (this is a partly academic pursuit).

The important part of the wrapper structure is here:

```cpp
template<typename K> struct Wrapper
{
    K node; // Element that is wrapped

    Wrapper() {};
    Wrapper(K impl) : node(impl) {};
    Wrapper(const Wrapper<K>& other) : node(other.node) {};

    const Wrapper<K> operator[](const char* key);
 
    //... Other stuff
}
```

My problem is that I am experiencing compile time errors when I attempt to chain multiple `[]` operations together.

The `operator[]` overload can be found here:

```cpp
// Returning by value since I am creating an object that goes out of scope.
// This is okay because the parsing is read only.
template<> const Wrapper<to_wrap> Wrapper<to_wrap>::operator[](const char* key)
{
    // It is safe to assume that node[key] produces a to_wrap type.
    return Wrapper<to_wrap>(node[key]);
}
```

With some examples of how it would be called:

```cpp
template<typename T> bool configure(T config)
{
   ​Wrapper<T> root(config);

   // Method A
   ​Wrapper<T> thing = root["field1"]["field2"];

   // Method B
   ​Wrapper<T> first_thing = root["field1"];
   ​Wrapper<T> second_thing = first_thing["field2"];
}
```

The compile-time error occurs if I attempt `Method A`. `Method B` yields the result I expect at compile and run-time: a `Wrapper` object that contains the appropriate `node`. The error from `A` is below:

```
error: conversion from ‘const char’ to non-scalar type ‘Wrapper<to_wrap>’ requested Wrapper<T> thing = root["field1"]["field2"];
```

This leads me to think there is an issue with how the compiler is inferring type, but I am not entirely sure. Any help/insights would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
const Wrapper<K> operator[](const char* key);
```

to

```
const Wrapper<K> operator[](const char* key) const;
```

or - better still - make const and non-const versions of `operator[]`.

```
Wrapper<K> operator[](const char* key);
const Wrapper<K> operator[](const char* key) const;
```

Your current `operator[]` returns a `const` object, **and** is not permitted to be used on `const` objects.

Comment: This was it. Wish I asked sooner. Would you be able to comment on where the `const char` part of the error message came from? Not sure what it was referring to by `const char` since the only place that type exists is in the key names I define.

Comment: I suspect it's trying to figure out what to do with `"field2"`.

Comment: @MKC -- [See this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at).  Note there are two overloads of `[]` for `std::vector`, one const and the other non-const.  You should follow this pattern.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Given that I only ever intend to use this wrapper to read, I suspect that I won't need the non-const version. However, I appreciate the resource!